# VB6 app 'Run as administrator' issue

Tags: vb6, activex, runas

I have a vb6 application that runs fine when double clicking the .exe.  When I right click the .exe and select 'run as administrator' (on a Windows 7 machine), I get an error: "Run-time error 429. ActiveX component cant create object"

What dll/com is missing?

Answer (score 3):

This seems pretty clear.

One or more DLLs and OCXs you are using was not properly installed and registered.  Most likely some of them have been virtualized, either in the filesystem and/or the registry.  They can only be seen by that one user when running under its standard-user context because the admin context doesn't have virtualization applied.  Log on as a second user and you'll see the same failure.

Installation needs to run under TrustedInstaller, or at least elevated.  That's the only way libraries can be placed and registered globally as they need to be.

Comment: +1. And if you need to find out which DLL or OCX it is, you could add some logging or error handling to find at which point in the code it fails. But its probably better just to install everything with admin priviliges

Answer (score 0):

Have the same problem and in my case I solved in this way:

- reference global system DLLs only from C:\Windows\SysWOW64 (ex. msxml6.dll)
- run VB6 IDE as Administrator and compile your program